# Ruby on Rails search function solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, so I have serveral questions to my search function.

Search View:

```
<p>
<%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p> Advanced_search: <%= check_box_tag "advanced_search", value = "1" %> </P>
<%= select_tag(:attribute, options_for_select([['Prename',0],['Lastname',1]])) %>
<%= text_field_tag :search%>
<%= submit_tag "Search"%></p>
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @stud = Student.search(params[:search], params[:advanced_search], params[:attribute])
end
```

Model:

```
def self.search(search, advanced_search, attribute)
    ary = []
    if advanced_search
        case attribute
        when '0'
            ary << Array(where(Student.arel_table[:prename].matches("%#{search}%")))
        when '1'
            ary << Array(where(Student.arel_table[:lastname].matches("%#{search}%")))
        else
            raise ArgumentError, 'Something strange happened! problem with select_tag in the search function'
        end
    elsif search
        case attribute
        when '0'
            ary << Array(where(prename: search))
        when '1'
            ary << Array(where(lastname: search))
        else
            raise ArgumentError, 'Something strange happened! problem with select_tag in the search function'
        end
    else
        Student.all
    end
    ary
end
```

Index View:

```
  <% @stud.each do |student_arr|%>
  <% student_arr.each do |student| %>
  <li> <%= student.prename + " " + student.lastname + " " + student._format_birthday + " DaZ: " + student.daz.to_s%>
  (<%= link_to "Details", action: "detail", id: student.id %>)
  (<%= link_to "Edit", action: "edit", id: student.id %>) </li>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

My solution works, I don't get duplicates, but the code look really badly and I have to say "look for pre- OR lastname". May anyone can help me with a better solution. 
For me it would be perfect if u are just searching for a Student and u don't have to say for what u are looking for (pre- or lastname) and u don't get duplicates. Maybe a Student name is "Peter Peter" (bad example, but it could happen^^), so I just want to get Peter once in my Student_array. Besides I would like to have the option to search for an explicit prename, so if there is Student called "Hans-Peter" and Student called "Hans" but I just want to find "Hans"...
Is there a way to realize this problems with less and more beautiful code?

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad english.. I'm doing my best :)
Bye Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, your code need a complete refactor. Here is the base to help you refactor your search logic:

```
# student.rb
def self.search(searched_string)
  searchable_columns = %w( prename lastname )
  sql_conditions = searchable_columns.map do |column_name|
    "#{column_name} ILIKE :searched_string"
    # use ILIKE if you are using PostgreSQL
    # use LIKE if you are using MySQL or SQLite
  end.join(' OR ')
  where(sql_conditions, searched_string: "%#{searched_string}%")
end
```

Any Student record having prename or lastname containing the string searched will be returned.

You would have to change your controller's call to the search method accordingly.

Comment: Wow! Thank u very much! I used ur solution and it works perfectly :) It doesnt matter if the first letter of the name is upcased or not, that's pretty awesome. There was just one problem with the line ""#{column_name} ILIKE :search".. I had to use LIKE instead of ILIKE. Maybe because I use SQLite3? I'm not sure.

Comment: @homior yes I forgot to mention the DB used: postgreSQL use `ILIKE`, MySQL and SQLite use `LIKE`. I'm glad my code helper you, most important thing is that you understand the logic and can reproduce it! Have fun with Rails :)

Comment: I'm not sure what this "end.join(' OR ')" is exactly doing. I know that sql_conditions will be "prename LIKE :search OR lastname LIKE :search". So if u use this "end.join(' OR ')", it will add an ' OR ', each time he goes through the loop except the last time?  (sry for english again^^)